# Binary Tree Level order traversal

Tags: java, binary-tree, traversal

Just out of curiosity, I was wondering if it would be possible to traverse a binary tree using nothing but a single recursively method.

I've already managed to traverse a binary tree using queue, but from some of the sites I've visited to understand how to even do it with queue; some did mention that it is also do-able with recursion. Some of the sites that mention the recursive method uses two or more method to work around the problem, but would it be possible to do it with just 1 recursive method?

Comment: not both/all method are recursive, I'm curious to see if it is possible to fit everything you need into a recursive method and still have it work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the traversal of binary tree with **one recursive method is possible**

```
void preorder (Node * root) {
   if(root!=null) {
       System.out.println(root->data);
       preorder(root->lchild);
       preorder(root->rchild);
   }
}
```

Similarly, you can do for inorder and postorder.

Comment: The user is asking for Level order traversel

Comment: Ohh right! Then breadth first search level order traversal is not possible without a queue. Coz recursion internally maintains a stack and breadth first search cant be implemented using a stack.

Comment: You cannot say it's not possible...it might be difficult though to find a workaround...

Answer (score 0):

I assume based on your title that you're looking for a **breadth-first traversal**. There are ways to do this without a queue or indeed any scaling in the amount of memory used, but they're pretty wasteful.

The one that comes to mind is [iterative-deepening depth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_deepening_depth-first_search), which involves traversing the tree in in/post order but ignoring every level of depth but the one you are currently on. Depending on the branching of your tree this can be as bad as O(n^2), though usually it is just a relatively slow O(n).

As described in the article, iterative-deepening depth-first search can also be used for non-tree graphs, which can be handy though probably isn't relevant in your case.